# Deploy environment variables to Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, environment-variables, continuous-deployment, firebase-hosting, github-actions

I use Firebase in React and when initializing Firebase, I use environment variables fetched from my .env file with `dotenv`. I want to build and deploy my React app to Firebase hosting, I use GitHub Actions with the following .yml workflow file:

```
name: Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: public
          path: public
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: public
      - name: Deploy
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

However, my build step fails (i.e. `npm run build`) because the environment variables are not found. If I hardcode the values instead of using my environment variables, the workflow is successful.

Do I need to do add my environment variables to GitHub secrets similar to how I added `FIREBASE_TOKEN` in my deploy step and add them to the workflow to be something like:

```
name: Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
        env:
          FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
          FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
          FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}
          FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
          FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
          FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}
          FIREBASE_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: public
          path: public
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: public
      - name: Deploy
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

I receive the same error, saying that it can't find the API token.

When I browse workflow files in other firebase-based React apps, I can't see anyone adding these environment variables like I have suggested. What is the proper way of handling environment variables in apps deployed to Firebase? Do they belong in the build or deploy step?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: To be clear, have you added your API key as a github secret, or just in an env file? Can you be a bit more specific about what the errors were, and the example file when it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Your custom env variables must start with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. 
Please take a look at this article [Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-temporary-environment-variables-in-your-shell).

As an additional note you can also run the `npm run build` along with your env variables passed as parameters like this:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY }} REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN }} REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DBURL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DBURL }} npm run build
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding a .env file you can easily add the secrets to github secrets.

[image]

Once the secrets are added to github secrets you can add them to env at the build process as follow in your workflow.

```
name: Firebase Deployment
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - feature/secrets_fix

env:
  API_KEY: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
  APP_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
  AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
  MESSAGE_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID }}
  PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
  STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
  TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.2
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        env:
          CI: false
        run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.2
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

`secrets.${YOUR_GITHUB_SECRET_NAME}`
Once they are mapped as above under env, you can easily retrieve them from react application using
`process.env.YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE`

Following is a example on firebaseConfig

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.APP_ID
};
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, you should add your **env** parameters to Github Secrets (https://github.com/your-project-name/settings/secrets/actions) and address them in `YAML` file, setting them up in the beginning of the file. Here's an example:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  REACT_APP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [17.4.0]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/
        
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3      
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: |
              npm install
              npm ci && npm run build --if-present      
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_APPNAME }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: APPNAME
```